# Meaning of $PWD in mapred-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need help to understand following configuration on mapred-site.xml.

```
<property>
      <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
      <value>$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure</value>
    </property>
```

what is value of $PWD (is it like normal pwd of linux) and $hdp.version ? Where these values are set?

Any idea?

Comment: Check this - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174990/what-is-pwd-vs-current-working-directory

Answer (score 0):

$PWD is the Pathname of the current Working Directory and $hdp.version is the version of Hortonworks Data Platform(HDP) that you are using. They are set in your `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/environment` or `~/.profile`